# Change the color of the text of QLcdNumber

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt4

Using PyQt4 and Python 3 do you know how I can change the color of a QLcdNumber during the runtime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't use this for some thime, but I think you had to change paletteForegroundColor and change segmentStyle to QLCDNumber::Filled or QLCDNumber::Flat